# How can I fix a hole in a hollow wooden door?

Tags: doors, door-frame

Recently the lock in my wooden door failed and the only way to open the door was to "motivate" the lock. Unfortunately the door was hollow and I ended up putting my foot through it.

Now, rather than buy a new door and use the old one as firewood. I would like to know the best way to fix it.

The problem I face is that the outer shell is quite thin with the only real wood being on the sides. I am going to need to figure out a way to "re-cover" the door and get the bits and pieces back in place.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: That isn't a "hole" in a door.  That is a completely f'ed up door.  A new 6 panel hollow door at big box is about $40.

Comment: Down voting because it's obvious that the door is significantly damaged and the answer is to just buy a new one.

Comment: Don't use the old door as firewood. The chemicals in the paints and glues will produce noxious fumes, and then you'll have multiple other problems too.

Answer (score 7):

Not worth the time and effort. Replace the door.

Comment: x2  That's about a $30-$40 door retail, you can probably find one for less if you have a ReStore or something similar around